# Meaning of こともあるもんです

Tags: grammar

How should I translate こともある in this sentence (response to '何それ?'):

> あなたが辞書を使うなんて、はなはだ珍妙なこともあるもんです

Literal translation of はなはだ珍妙なこともある would be 'there are also really odd things', but that makes no sense.

One suggestion seems to be that it means 'among other things' so I get:

> Because (もん), among other things (こともある), it's really odd that (なんて) you use a dictionary

Is this a correct translation? If so can anyone offer a suggestion as to how we arrive at that from the literal translation? (and why do I have to keep reaching for my advanced grammar book to read a children's story? It's really dispiriting.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latter part is in line with: "wow, strange things happen!"

もん ([ものだ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/17282/m0u/)) is used here emphatically to indicate emotion (hence I decided for "wow").

こともある literally stands for [occasionally](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B), but as the English verb *to happen* already covers the occasional aspect the meaning can be expressed just with  "things happen".

Comment: +1 even for the first sentence alone.

Answer (score 5):

Literal translation of ”こともある” is "It happens / takes place sometimes / Whatever happens happens - as reffered to by Donald RRumsfeld," e.g., "週中に会社を休むこともある - I happen to take a dayoff sometimes in a weekday."

In addition, you'd better to register the pattern, "....するなんて ...もんです（もんだ）" as a common set of phrase to mean a surprise and cynicism in your collocation list.

For example,

女の子がボクシングをするなんてたまげたもんです（もんだ）　－ Girls do boxing? It's a surprise.

豪華船で世界一周するなんて豪華なもんです（もんだ）　ー I heard you are going to make a trip around the world by a luxury liner. It's really gorgeous.

そのくらいでくたばるなんて、ひ弱なものですなア（もんですな）ー You are exhausted with that much exercise. What a feeble guy you are.

一千兆円も借金があってお金をじゃぶじゃぶ流すって、安倍もいい気なもんですなア　－　To flush a massive cash into the market with 1000 trillion-yen national debt behind, Abe is really taking things too easy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that ものだ is used here to indicate emotion, but this emotion is not "wow". Let me offer another explanation from my reference book:

> **～ものだ / ～ものではない** is used to express something that is obvious, or that obviously ought to be.
>
> Short expression for memorizing: 弱い者いじめをする**ものじゃないよ** = Weak people should not be treated badly!
>
> Examples of usage:
>
> *(father to his child)* もう１０時半だよ。早く寝なさい。子供は１０時前に寝る**ものだ。**
>
> だれにも一つや二つは苦手なことがある**ものだ。**

So, my translation would be **"You are using dictionaries and the like, but well, there are really weird things [in the world]."** And this "も" in "珍妙なこと**も**ある" implies, that using a dictionary is one of these "really weird things".

Hope it helps =)