# why ひどい神もいたもんだ　means "that's a mean god"?

Tags: set-phrases, word-requests

the english version of the material Im reading says "that's a mean god", and a friend told me that means "there is a bad god ,isn't it?" , but I don't understand why.
I know ひどい神 (bad,cruel, God)　I guess the もんだ　its a contraction of ものだ , but I still don't get it , what is もいた? , can someone explain all of this in detail please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's (酷い + 神) + も + 居た【いた】 + (もん + だ).

もんだ at the end is a contraction of ものだ, and this type of ものだ carries the sense of exclamation or surprise. So the sentence means something like "Wow, a bad God exists!" or "I'm surprised at the fact that such a cruel god exists!"

Related:

- [Meaning of こともあるもんです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28809/5010)
- [Function of に and meaning of ものだ in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17616/5010)
- [The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010)

**EDIT**: For this "past tense" いた, please see [Usage of plain i-adjectives or た form (悪かったｖ悪い、良かったｖいい etc）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21347/5010) and 
 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40888/5010

**EDIT 2**: For this も, please see: [Odd use of も has me stumped](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010) All in all, this is a combination of three (mild) exclamatory expressions!