# What would be the function of the ときたものだ?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

> 神無月とやらは大仰に礼をすると、興奮した調子で続けてきた。
>
> 「突然ですがお嬢さん！あなた、モデルになってみる気はありませんか！？」
>
> 「え……っ？」
>
> 急に発された言葉に、七罪は目を見開いた。
>
> 「も、モデル……って、あの、雑誌なんかに載ってる……？」
>
> 「はいッ！そのモデルです！」
>
> 神無月が力強くうなずいてくる。が、それに反して七罪は冷ややかに息を吐いた。
>
> なんと、モデル**ときたものだ**。七罪はこちらの世界で見た雑誌やテレビを思い起こした。

Hi. The context is that 神無月 disguised himself as a producer and invited 七罪 to be a model.

Question: what is the function or meaning of the ときたものだ? I used to think the ときたものだ has the nuance of 'add' or 'plus' and it is often used as a set phrase with '～上に', 'おまけに', 'さらに', etc.

But this ときたものだ doesn’t seem to mean this. Could you please shed some light on the phrase?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's とくる followed by exclamatory-ものだ.

**～とくる (literally "it comes out as ～):**

- [use of ときては in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62422/5010)
- [What does 「ときている」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24096/5010)
- [What does the word 「とくら」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35800/5010)

**～ものだ/～もんだ for exclamation:**

- [why ひどい神もいたもんだ　means "that's a mean god"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53893/5010)
- [Meaning of こともあるもんです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28809/5010)
- [Function of に and meaning of ものだ in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17616/5010)
- [What does "もんだなって" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13035/5010)

Put together, ～ときたものだ/～ときたもんだ works as a little cliched way of emphasizing, introducing or repeating a surprising statement. In other words, it adds the feeling of "ta-dah", "lo and behold" or "holy crap" to the sentence. "On top of that" is also usable when this expression comes at the end of a list, but it does not have the meaning of "in addition" by itself.

- どこにいるのか聞いたら「家で寝てました」ときたもんだ。
  I asked where he was, and believe it or not, he was like "I was sleeping at home"!
- (sales talk) この包丁がたった3000円と来たもんだ、さあ買っていけ！