Usage of と来たか in this sentence?
A「結論から言うと難しい、と思う……」
B そうなのか。がっかりしたが、どうしてそう思うのかは聞いておきたい。
B「後学のためにお伺いしても？」
A:「後学と来たか、いいけどさ。基本的に俺の力は天照に属してるものだ」
「後学のためにお伺いしても？」
The character here asks "can I ask you why you think it won't work, for future reference"?
Thus the character explains:
A:「後学と来たか、いいけどさ。基本的に俺の力は天照に属してるものだ」
I understand the second half of the sentence, but I'm stumbled on what to make of と来たか here. Especially given it's 来た and 来る. I assume it's akin to "If it's for future reference it's fine"

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82353/5010

This question is similar to: What would be the function of the ときたものだ?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
